# VB.NET - Data Driven Test won't build

Tags: .net, vb.net, mstest

I am attempting to write a MSTest data driven test in VB.NET. The code is pretty simple:

```
<TestMethod(), DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "AlgorithmTestData.CSV", "AlgorithmTestData#CSV", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)>
Public Sub ScoreAllData()
    Dim server = New Server.ScoringData

    Dim q1 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(1))
    Dim q2 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(2))
    Dim q3 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(3))
    Dim q4 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(4))
    Dim q5 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(5))
    Dim q6 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(6))
    Dim q7 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(7))
    Dim q8 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(8))
    Dim q9 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(9))
    Dim q10 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(10))
    Dim q11 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(11))
    Dim q12 = Convert.ToByte(TestContext.DataRow(12))

    Dim item = New AlgorithmItem(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12)
    Dim result = server.Score(item)
    Assert.AreEqual(47.86814688, result)        
End Sub
```

However, this code won't build. I get the following error (one for each call) pertaining to the TestContext.DataRow calls

```
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference
```

Every C# example i've seen uses the same static call. My project appears to have all the correct imports, including System.Data but this just won't build.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is in C#, but the same should work for you.
In our test class we have the following property. Seems to work for us (though I don't know if it is required or if someone just decided to add it for fun)

```
/// <summary>
///Gets or sets the test context which provides
///information about and functionality for the current test run.
///</summary>
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
```

Comment: That did it. I added a vb.net property and it now works. Apparently Microsoft uses property injection to inject the TestContext. Thanks!